# Is there a way to set Excel up whereby trailing spaces are visible?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know lots of techniques to remove trailing spaces from cells in Excel (e.g. `TRIM`), but sometimes I get given large sheets from other people which contain trailing spaces in dangerous places, where it's not obvious there's a problem because the trailing spaces exist in multiple places (so lookups etc still work) - but those trailing spaces cause unexpected problems later.

In Word and various publishing applications, there are options to show invisible characters. For example, in Word, it's called "Show non-printing characters", and it looks like this:

[image]

And text editors often show invisible characters in selected text, for example from Sublime Text 2:

[image]

Is there any kind of setting in Excel whereby invisible characters like trailing spaces could become visible? I'm not fussy about how they become visible, just that they do, across the whole sheet (i.e. not just in one selected cell).

Comment: See this answer for an example of how to TRIM() all cells: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21016303/4138090 I don't think the option that you'd like exists but this will likely solve your problem better anyway. It will skip any cells which have a formula so it should be fairly benign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Use a conditional format with the *whole table selected* and a formula to set the condition, I used

```
=OR(RIGHT(A1,1)=" ",LEFT(A1,1)=" ")
```

and all cells with a leading or trailing space got a red background and are double underlined, this will let you focus on those cells that have extra invisible spaces and as @fixed1234 suggested the underlines with show you where the spaces are. Cells that Excel treats as numbers do not show up with spaces even if they were entered with spaces (unless preceded by an apostrophe thus forcing it into a text format).

[image: Conditional formats on cells with spaces]

---

2: Find or edit a Font where the space character is not blank.

Some ideas about font editing in the answer linked https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19554/how-to-replace-a-character-in-a-font-with-another-character

Comment: Your #2 is clever.  It would help your answer if you could identify a font for which that was the case.  One shortcoming I can see is similar to using underlining alone.  The sheet will be full of "legit" spaces, so any trailing ones will be hiding in plain sight.  It would require looking at every cell.

Comment: Ooh, nice! I love the conditional formatting idea. I tried it on a sheet that had been causing me problems and it worked perfectly! I've put a question on the design site asking [is there any font where white-space or non-printing characters are visible, for proofing](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/is-there-any-font-where-white-space-or-non-printing-characters-are-visible-for) - if there is, I'll have the conditional format swap it in in place of the underlining

Comment: That formula doesn't seem to work for ` 11/19/2018` (notice leading space). I am not sure why. but I first selected the cells, then added the conditional formula. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that ``=TRIM(A1)<>A1`` (a) is shorter, and (b) will also catch values with multiple consecutive spaces, like “abc      def” (which might also cause problems; i.e., values that look equal will not be treated as equal).

Answer (score 3):

The best answer I've found [(Rick Rothstein, MVP - Excel)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/how-to-view-invisibles-in-excel/0ad4c4c5-7a5a-4ee0-a45d-d19388073f1d):

> If I understand what you want to do, then unlike Microsoft Word (which
>   allows you to do what you are asking for), **Excel does not have a way
>   of showing you the non-printing characters** I think you are interested
>   in. One reason may be because what you see in the cell may not be
>   "real"... it could come from, or be a concatenation from, other cells
>   on the sheet, or from a different sheet or even from a different
>   workbook. On top of that, the cell may be formatted to look the way
>   you see it, but the actual value in the cell may be completely
>   different. I think it would be a monumental task for the programmers
>   of Excel to figure out how to show you the "invisible characters" you
>   seek given the various ways in how the value displayed in the cell
>   could be formed to look that way.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I feared. If I was an Excel product designer, I'd add an option to have cells with no background colour slightly grey and then areas  with text white, so you could see a white-on-grey block where there are trailing spaces

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

1. Conditional formatting

   This method doesn't directly show the invisible characters, but it identifies cell that have them.  Select a cell and go to Conditional Formatting.  Select the option to use a formula.  Say the cell is A1.  Enter a formula like `=LEN(TRIM(A1))<LEN(A1)` and select a fill color.  Use `Copy`, then select the entire sheet, and `Paste Special | format` to copy the conditional formatting.  Any cell containing trailing spaces will be highlighted.
2. Underlining

   This solution will identify the trailing spaces but is not nearly as useful as conditional formatting because with everything underlined, you need to look at each cell to see if it is revealing anything.  Select the entire sheet, go to the font format window (right-click | format cell | fonts, or Fonts from the ribbon menu), and turn on underlining (turn off when you're done).  The underline will extend to the end of the content, so trailing spaces will be identifiable.

Comment: From Microsoft website we get "The TRIM function removes spaces from text except for single spaces between words." It would give a false positive if there were no leading or trailing spaces but there were a sequence of multiple spaces.  I like the underline and this can be used with the conditional format.

Comment: Why bother with `LEN`? `=TRIM(A1)<>A1` (a) is shorter, and (b) will catch the same problematic values.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ctrl+U (underscore) usually helps me to see all spaces in words

Comment: This answer was given six years ago.